# pandas.DataFrame.to_csv not exporting all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, missing-data

does anyone have an idea what could be causing pandas.DataFrame.to_csv not to export the complete dataframe?

```
print(len(df))
[77814 rows x 42 columns]
df.to_csv('filename.csv'))
```

The resulting csv files has 54470 lines and is missing block of data around 1/3 down the file. My data is time stamped to I can tell that the missing data is one large chunk and not random points throughout the file.
I'm working in python 3.6.5 and pandas is 0.22.0.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What software do you use to check the number of lines in the CSV?

Comment: I've opened it in a text editor to ensure it's not a re-import issue. The lines truly are not there.

Comment: what is the `type(df) ?`

Comment: `type(df)` is `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: can you check the length of the dataframe after doing a reset_index, I guess u are performing the operations before but not changing the index

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

I use this peice of code to add a header row to my CSV file

```css
df1 = pd.read_csv("/home/pip-tag/EXPERIMENTS/3376-M-CSV.csv", header=None)

df1.rename(columns={0: 'Creation TS' , 1: 'Processing TS', 2: 'TXID', 3: 'RSSI', 4: 'SEQNO', 5: 'CAP', 6: 'XAxis', 7: 'YAxis', 8: 'ZAxis', 9: 'X', 10: 'Y', 11: 'Z', 12: 'ADC Weight', 13: 'Calb Weight', 14: 'TS period', 15: 'Total Time'}, inplace=True)
df1.to_csv("/home/pip-tag/EXPERIMENTS/3376-M-Final.csv", index=False) # save to new csv file
```

after running this, the header row will be added, but not all rows are exported to the new CSV file (3376-M-Final)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot but in my case, I was trying to write to a CSV and it kept overwriting the data and saving only the last batch so I changed the mode from the default write [denoted by 'w'] to append [denoted by 'a'] like so:

```
df.to_csv(filename, index=False, mode='a')
```